# Client/Server app all in android

Tags: android

i'm making a POS app, but I need that the several devices use the same dabatase to implement prices/login/etc.

I'm thinking about one client APK in every phone/table and one APK in the "server" android device.

But I can't find any concise way of doing this.

What I found:

1. Using GoogleAppEngine. But I need the app working on LAN.
2. using a restful service with Jetty.

Is (2) the best option I have?

The data to transfer is not complicated, only json objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket programming. 
Here are some basic tutorial for it:
Client side: http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-server-implementation/

Server side: http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-server-implementation/